# Como fazer uma consulta no SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

No meu projeto o usuário deve fazer um cadastro para entrar, ao colocar os dados
nome, email e senha e ao clicar no cadastro eu gostaria de verificar se o e-mail já existe, como fazer ?

Eu tenho um método procurar em uma classe dao, mas não sei qual logica usar para implementar o pesquisar usuário, qual a melhor pratica?

```
    public List<Usuario> buscaUsuario(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO;";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        List<Usuario> usuario = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            Usuario user = new Usuario();
            user.setId(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_ID")));
            user.setNome(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CAMPO_NOME")));
            user.setEmail(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CAMPO_EMAIL")));
            user.setSenha(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CAMPO_SENHA")));

            usuario.add(user);
        }
        c.close();
        return usuario;
    }
```

Comment: Você deseja "melhorar" esse `buscaUsuario` ou quer ajuda em como construir outro método para verificar ser o e-mail existe na base de dados?

Comment: Gostaria de melhorar a pesquisa passando where

Comment: Existe varias maneira... como vc que usar no comando do sqlite, tente fazer um INSERT caso o email não exista usando o **IF NOT EXISTS**, ou tb tente usar o **db.insertOrThrow(...** ´bem legal e facil.

Comment: ou isso "SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE _id = "+ id +";"; para buscar um usuario especifico

Comment: No insert se eu colocar esse comando IF NOT EXISTS se ele não fizer o insert ele vai me retornar uma exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ler de um banco de dados use o método `query()` passando os critérios de seleção e as colunas desejadas. Os resultados da consulta são retornados em um objeto `Cursor`.

Para ver uma linha no cursor, use um dos métodos de movimento `Cursor`, que sempre deverão ser chamados antes de começar a ler valores. Geralmente, deve-se iniciar chamando `moveToFirst()`, que coloca a "posição de leitura" na primeira entrada nos resultados. Para cada linha, você pode ler o valor de uma coluna chamando um dos métodos do `Cursor`, como `getString()` ou `getLong()`. Para cada um dos métodos, você deve passar a posição de índice da coluna desejada.

Neste, veja como você poderia fazer:

```
/**
 * Este metodo busca um usuario pelo ID
 *
 * @param userID
 * @return
 */
public Usuario buscaUsuario(int userID){
    // instancia do objeto Usuario
    Usuario usuario = new Ususario();
    // Cariação do SQLiteDatabase a leitura do banco de dados
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    // criação do cursor no qual recebera a query d do usuario
    Cursor cursor = db.query("USUARIO", new String[]{"_ID", "CAMPO_NOME",
            "CAMPO_EMAIL", "CAMPO_SENHA"}, "_ID" + "= ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(userID)}, null, null, null, null);

    // verifica se o cursos retornou alguma resultado
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            usuario.setId(cursor.getInt(0));            // definição do ID retornado do cursor
            usuario.setNome(cursor.getString(1));       // definição do NOME retornado do cursor
            usuario.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));      // definição do EMAIL retornado do cursor
            usuario.setSenha(cursor.getString(3));      // definição da SENHA retornado do cursor
        } else {
            // caso não retornar nenhum usuario do cursor, o retorno da função será nula
            return null;
        }
    }
    // finaliza o SQLiteDatabase
    db.close();
    return usuario;
}
```

Para usar o método, basta criar um objeto do tipo `Usuario` no qual recebera o valor da busca.

Veja como seu código ficaria:

```
// aqui você instancia seu Handler extendendo o `SQLiteOpenHelper`
MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler(this);

// userID é o id do usuário no qual precisa buscar
Usuario user = db.buscaUsuario(userID);
```

Tudo isso escrito aqui, esta na documentação, [Como salvar dados em bancos de dados SQL](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=pt-br), para maiores detalhes.

> gostaria de verificar se o e-mail já existe, como fazer ?

Basta você criar uma método como este feito acima, porém passando o `email` como parâmetro. Caso retorne algum resultado, é que já existe um e-mail cadastrado na sua base de dados. Desta forma você pode verificar assim:

```
if(user!=null){
   // se entrou aqui é porque existe um usuário baseado na busca
} else {
   // se entrou aqui é porque NÃO existe um usuário baseado na busca
}
```

Comment: Talvez ajudasse ao entendimento se explicasse as partes que compõem(como se chama) o `db.query()`.

Comment: @ramaral vou fazer isso!

Comment: Esse campo ID não seria um Long? (Li em algum lugar que toda tabela criada no SQlite já tinha o campo _ID e que ele era um long) confere?